# How to create a reusable component which accepts a path and queryparameters, constructs the url, and fetches the url?

Tags: next.js, fetch-api

Im creating an application using NextJS which fetches movie data from a source in rapidapi: https://rapidapi.com/SAdrian/api/moviesdatabase

I attempted to create a reusable component which would render the movie data given the right path and query parameters.
The reusable component would work like this for example:

```
  <FetchingMovies
  path={`search/title/${params.movies}`}
  queryParams={{ limit: 50, page: 1 }}
/>
```

Then that line of code should render 50 movies in that specific path, but i have a problem, whenever i call this component theres an error fetching the data. Whenever i console.log my url from within the fetchingmovies component this is the url that appears: **URL {
href: 'https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com/titles/[object%20Object]',
origin: 'https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com',
protocol: 'https:',
username: '',
password: '',
host: 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com',
hostname: 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com',
port: '',
pathname: '/titles/[object%20Object]',
search: '',
searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
hash: ''
}**
AS you can see in a weird way the path prop gets converted to anobject when it is originally a string. Here is the function in the component that creates a url, then fetches the data, currently it doesnt work:

```
async function fetchData(path = '', queryParams = {}) {
  const apiKey = 'ab4537c209msh1ab343c03e3bafcp1edf2fjsn5bb095aa68c5';
  const baseUrl = 'https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com/titles';
  
  // Constructing URL with query parameters if provided
  let url = new URL(`${baseUrl}/${path}`);

  // Adding query parameters
  Object.keys(queryParams).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, queryParams[key]));

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': apiKey,
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
console.log(url)
  return res.json();
}
```

I would highly appreciate to know what wrong with my code, why that error happens, how can i fix it and create a reusable react component in nextjs which successfully takes in the path and query parameters as props and creates a url which can be fetched.